# use conditional statment to determine how TextField appears in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, conditional-statements

```
TextField (
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Need extra ice or have another request?',
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            //else {
            // decoration: InputDecoration(
            // hintText: Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false).specialNotes,
            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            // ),}
            onChanged: (newText) {
              Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                  .updateSpecialRequests(newText);
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
          ),
```

I want to make a conditional statement that determines whether the code above the commented code is read or the commented code below it gets read. Textfield is an array of children. However I try to do this, it breaks my code. The TextField invariably is no longer lit up in gold as it is when the code is working. The online suggestions have not been working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tenary operators

```
TextField (
            decoration: condition ? InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Need extra ice or have another request?',
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ): InputDecoration(
               hintText: Provider.of<OrderProvider>.specialNotes,
               contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
             ),
            onChanged: (newText) {
              Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context, listen: false)
                  .updateSpecialRequests(newText);
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
          ),
```

Comment: You can add your print statement in your initState. or you can convert this entire widget to a Function